# python webdriver chromedriver: unable to click on a button

Tags: python, button, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```html
<div class="dialog-ft">  
    <button mx-click="submit" data-spm-click="gostr=/alimama.11;locaid=decf8333e" class="btn btn-brand w100 mr10">confirm</button>   
    <button mx-click="close" data-spm-click="gostr=/alimama.11;locaid=d4df4de16" class="btn btn-gray w100">cancel</button> 
 </div>
```

there are 2 buttons on the page, and I need to click on the first to proceed my logic. I wrote some codes like:'

```
def locate_element_by_xpath(xdriver, xpath):  
element = None
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(xdriver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
    raise e
if element:
    return element
else:
    return False

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",
                            locate_element_by_xpath(driver, '//*[@id="magix_vf_code"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]'))
```

I can ensure that the xpath works well by testing print .text as 'confirm'

I got `TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) Error.`

I also tried the original way and got the same error:

```
dialog.find_element_by_class_name('dialog-ft').find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
```

can anyone please help have a look on this? Thank you.

Comment: Timeout was because the element identified by xpath did not appear on the DOM within 60 seconds. Check your xpath or wait longer.

Comment: is this button in some frame ?

Comment: Thanks. It's strange, if I print .text of the button, it's fine. but when I perform click on it, timeout error came.

Comment: It is like kindof dialog, but I've checked, it's div container,not fram or ifram. not sure how they archive this. 
if you can, you can have a look to http://pub.alimama.com/promo/search/index.htm?q=%E5%A5%B3%E8%A3%85&_t=1498511106485